# Connecting a USB device to Android

Tags: android, usb, mouse, hardware, host

I need to connect a USB device to a nexus 10. The device implements a mouse interface(Not really a mouse, but it uses the mouse interface to transfer data, that's how my customer built the device ).

I could not capture the mouse raw USB transfer in an app and I'm going to build a custom ROM for my Nexus 10. My question is - can I avoid that? Can I somehow access mouse raw events from Android?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If the device is properly implemented, you should receive input events through the regular channels. Not having any specifics on the device, it is hard to say what might be wrong.

You can use [InputManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/input/InputManager.html) to gather some information. It may be the device requires a [configuration file](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/input-device-configuration-files.html), or at worst its own driver (which you can't easily provide).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to detect to the device finally(Problem was in my code). Here is the fixed code:

BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);


        String message = "action:"+action+" device:"+device.getProductId()+" Vendor:"+device.getVendorId();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, 3000).show();    

        if(device.getVendorId()==LEVITICUS_VENDOR_ID)
        {
            if(action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED))
            {
                handleDeviceAttached(device);
            }
            if(action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED))
            {
                handleDeviceDettached(device);
            }
        }
    }
};

private void registerUsbReceiver() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);     
}
```